# Variance of the least squares estimator $\hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_{t=2}^n y_ty_{t-1}}{\sum_{t=2}^n y_{t-1}^2}$.

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation, time-series

I am working on a time series problem and I really am having trouble understanding many things.

The model we are using is AR(1) where
$$y_t = \beta_1y_{t-1}+e_t$$
and the least squares estimator of $\beta_1$ is
$$\hat{\beta_1} = \frac{\sum_{t=2}^n y_ty_{t-1}}{\sum_{t=2}^n y_{t-1}^2}$$

My goal is to show that 
$$Var[\hat{\beta}]= \frac{\sigma^2_e}{\sum_{t=2}^n y_{t-1}^2}$$

I understand that $Var[e_t]=\sigma^2_e$ because it is assumed that $e_t \sim N(0,\sigma^2_e)$.

The problem also mentions that $y_{t-1}$ are fixed.

This really confuses me, because how can $y_{t-1}$ be fixed while $y_t$ is not?

I want to simplify

$$Var\left[\frac{\sum_{t=2}^n y_ty_{t-1}}{\sum_{t=2}^n y_{t-1}^2}\right]$$

but I do not know the distribution of $y_ty_{t-1}$ and $y_{t-1}^2$ so I do not know how to proceed from here.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Knowing that $y_{t-1}$ is a constant, it is a straightforward simplification. No distribution required.

Comment: Rewriting: $\hat{\beta}_1=\beta+\frac{\sum e_t y_{t-1}}{\sum y^2_{t-1}}$, helps a lot.

Comment: Oh, I see now how you got that expression.  $\beta$ is a constant so its variance is $0$.  Now the latter part gets me.  Would it be that the denominator comes out as $(n-1)^2 y_{t-1}$ ?

Comment: I finally see what you two are saying.  Thank you very much!